# Error trying to rename columns with space in oracle table. Error - SQL Error : ORA- 00946 : missing TO keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, rename, alter-table

I have table named `employee`. In which , I wish to alter the column name from `Employee Name` to `Employee_Name` (note that the existing column name has a space!)

When I use the following command:

```
Alter table employee rename column Employee Name to Employee_Name
```

I am getting this error:

> SQL Error : ORA- 00946 : missing TO keyword

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Oracle doesn't know the space is part of the column name, you have to enclose it in quotes to make sure it recognizes it correctly:

```
Alter table employee rename column "Employee Name" to Employee_Name
```

Answer (score 3):

> I wish to alter the column name from 'Employee Name' to 'Employee_Name'

The problem lies in the fact that you used **[quoted identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129)** for **column name** while creating the table.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129),

> Database Object Naming Rules
>
> Every database object has a name. In a SQL statement, you represent
>   the name of an object with a quoted identifier or a nonquoted
>   identifier.
>
> - A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you
>     must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.
> - A nonquoted identifier is not surrounded by any punctuation.

You need to use **double quotation marks** around the existing column name to fix the problem:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE employee("employee name" VARCHAR2(10));

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE employee RENAME column "employee name" TO employee_name;

Table altered.
```