# I'm trying this query to change attribute name

Tags: sql, oracle

```
alter table car
rename column office-id to office_id
```

Why is it giving out "missing to keyword" error?

Comment: `office - id` e.q. `office minus id`. You want `"office-id"`.

Comment: What is the exact name of the column as listed in `user_tab_columns`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a potential solution:
[Error trying to rename columns with space in oracle table. Error - SQL Error : ORA- 00946 : missing TO keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533479/error-trying-to-rename-columns-with-space-in-oracle-table-error-sql-error-o)

```
alter table car rename column "office-id" to office_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need to enclose the column name in quotes

```
alter table car rename column "office-id" to office_id
```

Also you don't specify the dialect (the db is it Oracle, MS SQL, Postgres?)

Comment: The question has an <oracle> tag... And single quotes are for string literals, use double quotes for delimited identifiers (as in my comment.)